# D3/SVG: Why is this code slower when selection is changed?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a group selection passed to this function that I call using thisGroup.append("path").blah.blah but it's incredibly slow, perhaps 100 times slower. Can't tell because there's a 2 s delay but using svg.append like shown below is near instant. Can anyone tell me why? Although it works I have to repeat the translation that I did already for the group and it's messing up my svg element ordering.

```
for (var i = 0; i < listEdges.length; i++) {

    var lineSeg = [];

    //generate coordinates

    //replace like nodeGroup.append("path") and it become 100 times slower
    svg.append("path")
       .attr("d",line(lineSeg))
       .attr("stroke", chooseHSL(i))
       .style("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
       .attr("stroke-width", 5)
       .attr("fill", "none")
       .attr("transform","translate(580,260)");

 }
```

this is how my nodeGroup is declared

```
var nodeGroup = svg.selectAll("g")
                 .data(listNodes)
                 .enter()
                 .append("g")
                 .attr("id",function(d){ return "Group_" + trimWhitespace(d); })
                 .attr("transform","translate(580,260)");
```

and how svg is declared

```
var svg = d3.select("#container")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("id","svgContainer")

        .attr("viewBox","0 0 1300 610")
        .attr("perserveAspectRatio","xMinYMid")

        .attr("width", w  + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", h + margin.top  + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Personally I consider it bad form to mix loops with d3.js; the d3 data binding is usually a better way to do things than loops.

Back to your question, when you replace nodeGroup with svg, you essentially repeat the loop `listNodes.length` times (listNodes.length x listEdges.length executions instead of listEdges.length).

Maybe you should elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have some really sparse data which I placed around in a circle using a coordinate generator. In retrospect I should've created a new dataset, appended these coordinates and then created the DOM objects with the new data. I sort of continued onwards though so I have to use loops.

Comment: I understand your answer though, with svg I'm just calling the loop listEdges times but with nodeGroup I'm looping through all the groups each iteration of the loop because nodeGroup represent the selection of ALL the groups. Am I right based on your comment that using loops doesn't take advantage of D3's biggest strength which is the actual binding of data to DOM elements and that anywhere I have a loop there should be a way of doing the same thing without said loop?

Comment: Agreed with your first analysis. I find it better to prepare your dataset before doing the actually databinding, it greatly simplifies your d3 code.

Is it possible at all for you to go back and fix the data model? d3 itself provides a bunch of very useful array transformation and translation tools.

Comment: I'll probably rewrite my code with proper data joins. Thanks for the help!